# Getting a 'No apps are found for package name' error when trying to install an APK

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm getting a `E/AppIncrementalLogger: No apps are found for package name 'com.mypackage.name'` error in LogCat when trying to install an APK.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was I hadn't set a Launcher activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:label="ActivityName" android:name="com.mypackage.name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
         <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```